# Google External Login in MVC 5 C# (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, null, frameworks, google-authentication

I'm trying to add the Google External Login feature for one of my Web Applications using Visual Studio 2017 (MVC 5 .Net Framework). By following the exact steps given before, I'm not able to make it work. And after signing in with google account (previously assigned in test users), it always redirects to the login page. In debugging mode all the variables and properties are null.

Further, on my issue, I have tried each of the following steps (based on previous solutions from StackOverflow:-

1. Updating all related NuGet packages to the latest version.
2. Configuring Authorized Javascript and redirect URL based on my project
   (HTTP://localhost:{port number})
3. The application is in Test Mode (Test users were added).
4. The Code for Google authentication in (App_Start-> Startup.Auth.cs)
   looks something like this:

   app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

   ```
   app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
           {

               ClientId = "My Client ID Given in Google Developer Console",

               ClientSecret = "My Client Secret Given in Google Developer Console"
           });
   ```

I don't know if someone else has faced the same issue recently. And I tested this on Asp.Net Core project, and it works fine. But it does not work in MVC 5 Framework.
Please advise if any.

Best

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0?force_isolation=true

Comment: Also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0#remoteauthenticationhandlertoptions-vs-authenticationhandlertoptions

Comment: jdweng: I'm using .Net Framework, I don't wanna change my project to Core

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe they stopped supporting dot net framework.

Comment: reaz: I don't think so, how about other applications build with .net. But anyway, it is a weird issue.

Comment: I hope stack overflow professionals, remove some similar (old) solutions because most of them have become confusing as nowadays they don't work.

Comment: The auth2 should be the same in Net and Core.  Microsoft in getting Core working is also fixing issues with Net.  You should be using Net 4.7.2 or later with VS and then targeting MVC 5.  So source should be the same just the target is different.

Comment: jdweng: thanks for your solutions, actually I'm using the .net 4.7.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is related to HTTP , so you need to use HTTPs instead. Please, follow these steps:-

- Right Click on your project name-> Properties.
- In Properties window enable SSL.
- Copy the entire SSL URL (the port number is different than HTTP).
- paste your new SSL URL to Authorized Redirect URL in Google Developer Console. e.g
- When you run your application in visual studio. Don't forget to change HTTP to HTTPs and change the port number before trying to singing via google.
- The complete Authorized Redirect URL is as below:

**Authorized Redirect URL :** https://localhost:{new port number}/signin-google

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't even try because when you publish to your website, it won't work.  Google signin for .net will only work on localhost.  Instead, use onetap which is 100% brower side.  I was able to figure out onetap in a day by using code found here: https://googleonetap.developer.li/

Answer (score -1):

From the Google APIs API Manager, visit the Credentials tab to obtain the Client ID. Download to save a JSON file with application secrets. Copy and paste the ClientId and ClientSecret into the UseGoogleAuthentication method found in the Startup.Auth.cs file in the App_Start folder. If ClientId and ClientSecret values are not valid it doesn't work.
For example,

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
         clientId: "001-010.apps.googleusercontent.com",
         clientSecret: "01000100000");
```

Comment: This one was already applied, but i didn't include the keys in my code block here.